# Drag-Sort ListView horizontal items

Tags: android, list, listview

I've been googling for some time now, but  haven't found any information if it's possible to have items in [DSLV](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) horizontally arranged. I know that's not possible with plain ListView, but there are some implementations which allow horizontal arrangement.

Does anyone know if this is possible? Thx for any info.

Comment: how to implement drag-sort horizontal-list-view? have you found it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Drag-Sort ListView class extends the basic ListView including all its limitations.

Unfortunately there is no provision in DSLV to handle horizontal arrangement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18841297/android-control-for-simple-drag-and-drop-boxes , here it said that its easy to implement and you are saying its not possible !! horribly both answer is accepted !!!