# Android control for simple drag and drop boxes

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, controls

I want to have 1 line of items at the top of the app, inside each box will have like an icon or a letter.  You can arrange them in any order, horizontally.  Really easy to swap, not like hold and then move.  What kind of control would I use for this?

Comment: A combination of [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BZIvjMgH-Q) and [this](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2013/09/19/crossing-boundaries-with-the-new-android-viewoverlay/) should get you started. I've never done anything like it, so I'm not even going to try and post an answer.

Comment: @y2k not clear enough.can you explain it in details? (If possible then post some screen shots.)

Comment: Do these items have actions if clicked? Are they clickable?

Comment: can you share example code of your combination ?? or link for demo complete solution !!??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all let me clarify the task a bit. Do you need just a predefined set of items in the horizontal list *(option A)*?

[image]

Or a horizontal list with scrolling *(option B)*:

[image]

Let's assume for a moment `option A` is relevant, so you'll need:

1. horizontal list implementation
2. proper drag and drop handling

**Step 1**

There are several horizontal list implementations available, but some of them are old and unsupported, so I'd suggest to check [Horizontal Variable ListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView):

> Horizontal ListView for Android. Based on the official ListView google
>   code. It supports almost all the features of the ListView widget.
>   There are minor differences in the attributes supported like
>   "dividerWidth" instead of the default "dividerHeight".

BTW it supports `Android 4.2.2`, please also see [demo example](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView/blob/master/Demo/src/it/sephiroth/android/sample/horizontalvariablelistviewdemo/MainActivity.java).

**Step 2**

What you actually need at this point is just to handle drag and drop actions properly.

The simplest solution is to follow standard and well-known example: [TouchInterceptor class](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/TouchInterceptor.java) used in the Music application. It extends `ListView` so it should not be a problem to use the same approach with [Horizontal Variable ListView](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView).

Pay special attention to:

```
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
```

and

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
```

**Step 3: Advanced implementation**

Personally I think `option A` can only be used as a demo, so you have to address scrolling problem as well. Examples above show how to handle scrolling, but it might be a case you need a bit more.

[image]

There is another project (discontinued again) which can be used as an advanced example, because it solves several issues, supports animation, etc:

> [DragSortListView (DSLV)](https://github.com/bauerca/drag-sort-listview) is an extension of the Android ListView that
>   enables drag-and-drop reordering of list items. It is a major overhaul
>   complete rewrite of the TouchInterceptor (TI) meant to give
>   drag-sorting a polished feel. Some key features are:
>
> - Clean drag and drop
> - Intuitive and smooth scrolling while dragging.
> - Support for heterogeneous item heights.
> - Public startDrag() and stopDrag() methods.
> - Public interface for customizing the floating View.
>
> DragSortListView is useful for all kinds of prioritized lists:
>   favorites, playlists, checklists, etc.

It seems to be well-documented and easy to understand. Switch from vertical to horizontal mode should not be that hard.

```
public class DragSortListView extends ListView {


    /**
     * The View that floats above the ListView and represents
     * the dragged item.
     */
    private View mFloatView;

    /**
     * The float View location. First based on touch location
     * and given deltaX and deltaY. Then restricted by callback
     * to FloatViewManager.onDragFloatView(). Finally restricted
     * by bounds of DSLV.
     */
    private Point mFloatLoc = new Point();

    private Point mTouchLoc = new Point();

    /**
     * The middle (in the y-direction) of the floating View.
     */
    private int mFloatViewMid;

    /**
     * Flag to make sure float View isn't measured twice
     */
    private boolean mFloatViewOnMeasured = false;

    /**
     * Watch the Adapter for data changes. Cancel a drag if
     * coincident with a change.
     */ 
    private DataSetObserver mObserver;

    /**
     * Transparency for the floating View (XML attribute).
     */
    private float mFloatAlpha = 1.0f;
    private float mCurrFloatAlpha = 1.0f;

    /**
     * While drag-sorting, the current position of the floating
     * View. If dropped, the dragged item will land in this position.
     */
    private int mFloatPos;
```

Comment: for **DragSortListView (DSLV)** how to implement **vertical to horizontal mode** ???

Comment: because this link says its not possible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047336/drag-sort-listview-horizontal-items